# How do I add two points together in Java OpenCV?

Tags: java, opencv, opencv3.0

I was wondering how to add two points together in Java?
I am trying to convert some C++ code to Java.

Here is the C++ code:

```
    for (cv::Rect &eye : eyes) {
        rectangle(frame, faces[0].tl() + eye.tl(), faces[0].tl() + eye.br(), cv::Scalar(0, 255, 0), 2);
    }
```

And here is what I have so far in Java:

```
    Rect[] faces = myFaces.toArray();
    Rect[] eyes = myEyes.toArray();

    for (Rect eye : eyes)
        Imgproc.rectangle(frame, HELP!, HELP!, new Scalar(255, 0, 0), 2);
```

and how would I do this in terms of my Java app?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18975813/how-to-add-2-org-opencv-core-point-objects-in-android

Comment: so... how would i do this in terms of my app?